# Safari 6's New Developer Toolbar doesn't show Form Data in XHR/AJAX Requests

Tags: safari

Safari recently went to version 6 (Lion/Mtn Lion) and they've changed over from the standard webkit dev tools to one that's much more XCode looking, my problem other than the OCD of not liking things change is that in the resource tab (or anywhere you can track down the DataService.aspx/AJAX calls) I can no longer see the form data that I am passing.

Can anyone point me to where I can find that data so I don't have to console out my params when I'm testing new data service/backend calls?

I've logged a bug with Apple, they've marked it as a duplicate so hopefully they've received enough requests to fix this, until then I'm continuing to use chrome as the webkit developer is the same as safari's old version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find this info in Instrument tab (stop-watch icon). In the left sidebar thers Timelines row, click the grey circle (record button) on the right. Then click to Network Requests where you see all reqs, and you have to click small icon on the right oc request to display response headers and all form data are available in right panel. Panel can be hidden same as left one (in case you dnt see it).
Unfortunately there are no query pamaters listed, according to [this disscussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4142475?start=0&tstart=0). I belive its a bug in safari

Edit 15.May 2013: This bug was fixed in Safari 6.0.3.

Comment: I've submitted a bugreport as well.

Comment: So the short answer is no you can't see the request's query data. The rest of this answer is not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there's no way to show the request parameters.

This goes even further. I can't see the JSON response data either (no clickable arrows to show the containing Javascript objects within the JSON, just pure text)

I think we have to switch to Firefox /w Firebug or regular Webkit in order to get XHR monitoring...

Answer (score 1):

Guys if you want to see post data in safari 6 which is not possible right now, install the firebug lite extension and there you go you have the post data.
I used it and it works great with safari 6

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12466203/419

Answer (score 0):

Actually the request headers, response headers and query parameters are in the details sidebar on the right when using the resources view or if you click to see the content of a request in the Timelines/Network Requests view. Took me a few minutes to find that too.

Comment: You can see the Request Headers + Response Headers but you CANNOT see the Form Data you pass along, you can see the response however there is no JSON tab like there used to be for easy viewing without going to jsonlint.  

I've had to revert to Chrome for now as I'm not about to console out every param I'm passing in. On that note is it just me or is console.log() incredibly slow now, I know I don't have the worlds fastest machine just the newest 2012 MB Air 8GB RAM etc...

Answer (score -3):

If you need to see what the device is actually sending and your server is on a Windows Machine  I use http://www.Wireshark.org and check on the server side of things. No interpretation by any WebKit stuff and very valuable (such as issue with iOS and the 'Blob' data). Similar network snooping should exist on Mac as well.

Comment: Far too complex compared to just using another browser, besides, I've found if I open 10 tabs in safari it runs upwards of 1GB of memory, in chrome it's 1/3 of that. I don't see myself returning to Safari anytime soon.