# Safari 6 Developer Tools XHRs Post Data

Tags: safari, ria

Is it just me, or is the body of the request no longer available?  I am looking Resource (^1) -> XHRs.

Also, is there a way to order these chronologically, as opposed to alphabetically?

I'm looking here[image]

Answer (score 1):

Guys if you want to see post data in safari 6 which is not possible right now, install the firebug lite extension and there you go you have the post data.
I used it and it works great with safari 6

Answer (score 0):

in answer to your second question, you can view them chronologically by clicking on the stopwatch icon--two over from the page icon you have selected.

regarding your first question...no, it is not just you.  I can't find any post data either, nor do I see decoded json, which they used to show if the response was application/json

Comment: On the stopwatch panel, there is no way to filter, to only see xhrs, from what I can tell....

Comment: sadly, that is true.  Plus it will stop recording data on the timeline once it decides the entire page has loaded.  Although you can start it again manually.